# Database Error - Only in certain browsers

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, cpanel

I recently switched web host to a new company (chosting.dk), and now I've run into an odd phenomena. In certain browsers (currently Chrome and IE) I get the following error when I try to access my website, www.e-drift.dk:

> **A Database Error Occurred**
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

However, when I use my Thor browser (based on Firefox), there is no issue. It worked earlier today, and I have not changed the `database.php` config file since (I am using CodeIgniter). Also, I had a similar issue earlier, if i tried to enter http://e-drift.dk (without "www"). Is there any logical explanation for this, or do I need to contact my host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a DNS propagation issue.

I guess with Chrome and IE you use your default DNS to resolve your domain name, and with Tor an other one.  So you are actually accessing your new website only with Tor at the moment.

You just have to wait for the DNS to propagate.

Comment: Okay, while annoying, at least it is a low-tech solution. I am still confused on why it worked, and then stopped working again though?

Comment: It's very common. All of this is normal during propagation.

Comment: Okay, I was warned about that, I just thought it was fixed, once it started working. Didn't know it could stop working again. Thanks for enlightening me :-)

Comment: propagation can take up to 24 hours, although personally (UK) it is less than 12 hours.